# Single-Select Checkbox group in Monotouch.Dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am using this code to put a Checkbox group in a MonoTouch table and the update the values based on items checked:

```
var applescheck = new CheckboxElement ("Apples", false, "purchase");
var orangescheck = new CheckboxElement ("Oranges", false, "purchase");


var Purchases = new Section () {

    applescheck,
    orangescheck


};

applescheck.Tapped += () => {


    orangescheck.Value = false;


};

orangescheck.Tapped += () => {


    applescheck.Value = false;


};
```

However, although this does update the checkbox item's value, the checkbox that appears still stays there when the items value is false. Is there a way to update that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your events to the following

```
applescheck.Tapped += () => {
    orangescheck.Value = false;
    orangescheck.GetActiveCell().Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
};

orangescheck.Tapped += () => {
    applescheck.Value = false;
    applescheck.GetActiveCell().Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
};
```

The reason is that CheckboxElement.Value is simply a field, setting it has no side effect. To make a change you need to get the UITableViewCell that is associated with the element and apply the change there.